# Flux of particles not uniformly distributed

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section

I am puzzled by this issue. When introducing the cross section, the flux F is defined as the number of particles over unit area and over unit time. The flux is then used to obtain the cross section from the rate of interactions R and the number of targets $N_T$:

$$
\sigma = \frac{R}{F*N_T}
$$

Let us now suppose we have a beam of particle not uniformly spread over a target. That is not unusual, since most beams are gaussianly shaped. The flux then should depend on the position, as the derivative of the number of particles over the surface. In this case, should not the cross section itself depend on the position? And if that so, how do you relate the cross section to the total rate of interactions?

Comment: How big is the beam? How far from the interaction region are your detectors? What is the maximum difference in actual emission angle and nominal emission angle? How does that compare to other resolutions in your system?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this depends on which cross section you are referring to. The differential cross section has position dependence - it basically says what proportion of incoming flux would arrive in a box at given co-ordinates. By "cross section" here I think you mean total cross section which is the integral of the differential cross section over all positions. This then represents something like the the rate or probability for your process to occur.

Answer (score 0):

There are various definitions of flux and, related to it, the fluence of a particle beam. For the moment let me stick with your definition of flux as the number of particles over unit area and over unit time. For the equation you presented to be valid, if $F$ is flux, then $R$ has to be the interaction rate *per unit area* at the same position on the target. So, no, the cross section does not depend on the location on the target, the interaction rate does.

Another way to use this equation is to regard $F$ as flux integrated over the surface of target, and $R$ the total interaction rate. This is the more common use of this equation. Again, the cross section does not depend on the position.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still confused. You say that the equation is valid if F and R are both expressed per unit area (and unit time), or if both are integrated over the surface. But the cross section should have the dimensions of an area, so how does this make sense? Is $N_T$ a density then?